# thymeleaf errors

Tags: template-engine, thymeleaf

Here is my template sample:

```
<tr th:with="negNumber = ${myNum < 0}">
...
</tr>
```

And I got the following exception message:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "th:if" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hm, not familiar with thymeleaf, but replacing `<` with `&lt;` would probably solve your problem.

Comment: already tried but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML establishes that the < and > symbols should not be used in attribute values, and so they should be substituted by `&lt;`and `&gt;`

Example:

```
th:if="${prodStat.count} gt; 1”
```

Note that textual aliases exist for these operators: gt(>), lt(<), ge(>=) and le(<=). Also eq
(==) and neq(!=).

I hope this should solve your problem....

Answer (score 0):

The <, >, ", and & signs should be escaped inside tag attributes. 
use `&lt;` solve your problem.